# Do-While loop output is undefined

Tags: javascript

the console shows undefined for the following loop. the issue is in `array[i]` 
as it says i is undefined but it is the index for the loop elements. I don't want to change the x to I as I want to run the code only once and test that it will stop as x is not < 5.

```
let x = 5;
let i;
let array = ["x", "y", "z"];
do {
  console.log(array[i]); //statement
  i++; //increment
} while (x < 5); //condition
```

Comment: `5 < 5` is `false`. It's not really clear why `x` exists, though - what is the point of that variable? Moreover, `i` is `undefined` since you never give it an initial value, therefore `i++` would not really "increment".

Comment: Please try changing `let i;` to `let i = 2;`. And the console should display `"z"`.

Comment: If you just want to iterate over the array prefer a `for .. of ...` loop over a `while` or one of the many array methods like `forEach()`, `map()` etc. depending on your exact use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem with your code is that you initialised i without difining it `let i;` and then you are incrementing it `i++`,
set `let i = 0;`

```js
let x = 5;
let i = 0;
let array = ["x", "y", "z"];
do {
  console.log(array[i]); //statement
  i++; //increment
} while (x < 5); //condition
```

now if x is not less than 5 then the loop will run once
but there will be a problem that if x is less than 5 then loop will run infinitely so instead of just `x < 5` dot `x < 5 && i < array.length`

```js
let x = 4;
let i = 0;
let array = ["x", "y", "z"];
do {
  console.log(array[i]); //statement
  i++; //increment
} while (x < 5 && i < array.length); //condition
```

now it will work just fine !